# PrepareForSegue with UITableViewController - Pass data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am having a huge problem with my code. My question is, how can I get the data from the tableviewcell the user clicks on to a detail viewcontroller.

I am already getting the data out of an array and displaying it in my tableviewcontroller, but how can I pass that data through to a new viewcontroller using prepareForSegue?

This is my code for displaying data in the cells.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
    let cellIdentifier = "MealTableViewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MealTableViewCell

    // Fetches the appropriate meal for the data source layout.
    let meal = meals[indexPath.row]

    cell.nameLabel.text = meal.name
    cell.photoImageView.image = meal.photo
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = meal.description
    cell.servedWithLabel.text = meal.servedWith

    return cell
}
```

The problem is, that calling a prepareForSegue outside of that means that I cannot use for instance meal.name to pass the name through to the detail viewcontroller? What to do?

Hope you guys can help me - I have been struggling with this for some time now :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by Arun, you need to use `-prepareForSegue`. Here's what I'd do to pass something to your detail view controller (say `meal.name`)

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Use this to determine the selected index path. You can also store the selected index path in a variable using -didSelectRowAtIndexPath
    let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)

    // Get the relevant detail
    let meal = meals[indexPath.row]

    // Create reference and pass it
    let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! MyDetailViewController
    detailViewController.mealName = meal.name

}
```

And eventually, just hook up the `UITableViewCell` with `MyDetailViewController` using your `Storyboard` (and select whatever presentation and transition style you prefer)

**Edited for Swift 4**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell)

    // Get the relevant detail
    let meal = meals[indexPath!.row]

    // Create reference and pass it
    let detailViewController = segue.destination as! MyDetailViewController
    detailViewController.mealName = meal.name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click a cell. It will call  `didSelectRow`. In `didSelectRow` save the `indexPath.row` and do `performseguewithidentifier`

Now in `prepareForSegue` get the object from the array using `meals[selectedIndex]` and assign to `detailViewController` `Objects`.

Make sure `segue` is from `ViewController` to `ViewController`.